# не показываются балуны у меток

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Я пытаюсь добавить свои метки с кастомными балунами, но проблема в том что сами метки добавляются, но балуны не открываются. Для своей реализации я использовал пример [отсюда](https://github.com/mmarkelov/react-yandex-maps-layout/blob/b0c69a1f90602fe89fcaebca39d2cb8430e28bd9/src/App.js#L16), но в нем реализовано с теги в самом .В моем случае эти маркера будут добавляться при нажатии на кнопку. Я не понимаю откуда он взял переменную index, и добавил это переменной key у Placemark, хотя в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html)этого нет. Был бы рад любой подсказке. Спасибо.
Вот мой способ вывода.
Компонен УМар

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { YMaps, Map, Clusterer , Button,Placemark } from '@pbe/react-yandex-maps';
import InnerLayout from './InnerLayout';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
const mapState = {
    center: [55.7924886417031, 49.12233672582469],
    zoom: 9
};

const YMap = () => {
    
    const placemarkRef = React.useRef(null);
    const mapRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [canAddPlacemark, checkAddPlacemark] = useState(false);
    const [ymaps, setYmaps] = useState(React.useRef(null));
    const [openedDescription, openDescription] = useState(null);
    const [clusterBalloon, setClusterBalloon] = useState(null);

      const closeDescription = () => {
        setClusterBalloon(null);
        openDescription(null);
      };
    const createPlacemark = (coords) => {
        return new ymaps.current.Placemark(
            coords,
            {
                iconCaption: "loading.."
            },
            {
                preset: "islands#violetDotIconWithCaption",
                draggable: true
            }
        );
    };
    const getAddress = async (coords) => {
        placemarkRef.current.properties.set("iconCaption", "loading..");
        await  ymaps.current.geocode(coords).then((res) => {
                const firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                const newAddress = [
                    firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length
                        ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities()
                        : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                    firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                ]
                    .filter(Boolean)
                    .join(", ");

                placemarkRef.current.properties.set({
                    iconCaption: newAddress,
                    balloonContent: '     <div> <input type="button" onClick={() => { openDescription(index);}} value="Подробнее"/> </div>'
                });
                regionName =firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas()[0]; 
            })
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (document.getElementById('balloon') && clusterBalloon) {
          ReactDOM.hydrate(
            <InnerLayout
              openDescription={openDescription}
              openedDescription={openedDescription}
              {...clusterBalloon}
            />,
            document.getElementById('balloon'),
          );
        }
      }, [clusterBalloon, openedDescription]);

    const getLayout = (Component, props) => {
        if (ymaps) {
          const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Component {...props} />);
          const Layout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            `<div id="balloon">${html}</div>`,
            {
              build: function() {
                Layout.superclass.build.call(this);
                ReactDOM.hydrate(
                  <Component {...props} />,
                  document.getElementById('balloon'),
                );
              },
            },
          );
    
          return Layout;
        }
        return null;
      };
      const openCluster = e => {
        const cluster = e.get('cluster');
        if (cluster) {
          if (!clusterBalloon) {
            setClusterBalloon(
              cluster.state.get('activeObject').properties.getAll(),
            );
          }
    
          cluster.state.events.add('change', () => {
            const activeObject = cluster.state.get('activeObject');
            console.log(activeObject.properties.getAll().index)
            console.log(clusterBalloon.index)
            if (
              !clusterBalloon ||
              (clusterBalloon &&
                activeObject.properties.getAll().index !== clusterBalloon.index)
            ) {
              setClusterBalloon(activeObject.properties.getAll());
            }
          });
        }
      };
    const addMarkers = () =>{
        let POINTS = [[55.79424260833246, 49.68814042729016],[55.62832515119459, 49.11135820072768],[55.910118447321, 48.70761064213393]]
        
        for (let index = 0; index < POINTS.length; index++) {
            const element = POINTS[index];

        var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
                preset: 'islands#invertedVioletClusterIcons',
                groupByCoordinates: false,
                balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity,
                clusterBalloonItemContentLayout: getLayout(InnerLayout, {
                  openedDescription,
                  openDescription,
                  ...clusterBalloon,
                }),
                balloonopen:{openCluster},
                balloonclose:{closeDescription}
        })

        var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
            element,{
                balloonContentHeader:"title"
            }
            , {
                //  Балун будем открывать и закрывать кликом по иконке метки.
                hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
                balloonContentLayout: getLayout(InnerLayout, {
                element,
                index,
                openedDescription,
                openDescription,
              }),
              balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity,
                
            }
            );
        clusterer.add(placemark)
        mapRef.current.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
        }
    }
    const onMapClick = (e) => {
        if (canAddPlacemark){
            let objectManager = new ymaps.current.ObjectManager();
            objectManager.options.set('geoObjectInteractivityModel', 'default#transparent');
                const coords = e.get("coords");
                if (placemarkRef.current) {
                placemarkRef.current.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
            } else {
                placemarkRef.current = createPlacemark(coords);            
                mapRef.current.geoObjects.add(placemarkRef.current);
                placemarkRef.current.events.add("dragend", function () {
                    getAddress(placemarkRef.current.geometry.getCoordinates());
                });                
            }
            getAddress(coords);
        }
    };



    return (    
        <YMaps query={{ 
                        // load: "package.full" , 
                        apikey: "" }}>
            <Map defaultState={{
                    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
                    zoom: 9
                }} 
                modules={["Clusterer","Polygon","GeoObject","geoQuery","control.ZoomControl", "control.FullscreenControl","Placemark", "geocode", 
                "geoObject.addon.balloon","borders", "ObjectManager",'geoObject.addon.balloon','clusterer.addon.balloon',
                'templateLayoutFactory']}
                style={{
                    flex: 2,
                    height: "calc(100vh - 57px)"
                }}
                onClick={onMapClick}    
                instanceRef={mapRef}
                onLoad={ymaps => setYmaps(ymaps)}
                state={mapState}
            >
                <Button  onClick={addMarkers} data={{ content: 'Вывод маркеров' }} options={{ float: 'right' }} />
            </Map>
        </YMaps>
    )
}

export default YMap;
```

Компонент для отображения содержимого балуна

```
import React from 'react';
const InnerLayout = ({ openedDescription, index, openDescription, point }) => {
  if (openedDescription !== index) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            openDescription(index);
          }}
          value="Подробнее"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div>{"point.title"}</div>;
};

export default InnerLayout;
```